# O candescent NUI tem suporte para o novo Kinect?

Tags: kinect

Alguém sabe se o Candescent NUI tem suporte para trabalhar com o novo Kinect?
Não encontrei nada na internet que me apontasse isso ou o contrário. Para trabalhar com o novo Kinect usa-se ou o Microsoft SDK 2.0 ,ou OpenNI 2, ou NITE 2, porém não sei se esses middlewares tem suporte no Candescent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código foi portado e pode ser encontrado [aqui](https://github.com/VentaApps/Candescent-NUI-20148-for-Kinect-V2), porém necessita das seguintes dependências para funcionar: `OpenNI.net.dll`, `OpenNI64.dll`, `XnVNITE.net.dll` and `Microsoft.Kinect.dll` (Kinect SDK V2 dll).

[Traduzido de Stack Overflow (en)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177590/kinect-2-hand-detection-with-candescent-nui/30192074#30192074)